# How to switch between two latest windows in tmux?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

GNU Screen has <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> to switch between the two latest windows.

How to do it in `tmux`?

Comment: that's easily answered yourself question. Another one — which is a way harder to answer is *how to switch to the last window*

Answer (score 134, accepted):

To do this in tmux, you do

<kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>

(that is an 'L').  This assumes you have left <kbd>Ctrl-B</kbd> as your activation key.

If you want to use the same keypresses as screen,  then add the following to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a last-window
```

The first sets <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> as your activation key, the second says <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> after activation should go to the last window.

Answer (score 5):

Paul's answer is correct, but it *seems* to leave you without a way to type ^A.

See [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19072/using-ctrlb-in-less-within-tmux) for details, but essentially you can do this to get a `C-a` (^A) if you need one:

```
bind-key v send-prefix
```

Now if you type `C-a v` you'll get a ^A.

Answer (score 5):

To follow on to fbicknel and Paul:

you can

```
bind-key C-a last-window
bind-key a send-prefix
```

which will let you use a screen-like "ctrl-a a" to insert a 'ctrl a'

Answer (score 2):

I added:
`bind-key l last-window`
Into my tmux config file which by default is at `~/.tmux.conf`.
Reload tmux, switch windows at least once and press:
<kbd>ctrl+B</kbd> (default prefix) + <kbd>l</kbd> (lower-case L) works like a charm!