# More terminals than panes tmux

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen

I'm trying to migrate to tmux from gnu-screen.  There is one feature in screen that I can't figure out how to do in tmux.  Specifically, with screen I have one window and I can split that into multiple panes and, most importantly, I can have more pseudoterminals than panes.  For example, I'll often have two panes but will frequently swap between three different terminals.

In tmux, I seem to always have just as many pseudoterminals as I do panes. What set up and commands will give me the behavior I like in screen in tmux?

Comment: Would this not be better on unix and linux?

Comment: Similar vein to http://superuser.com/questions/429558/how-to-switch-between-two-latest-windows-in-tmux

Comment: Given the lack of responses, I guess you're right @djsmiley2k

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317323/108618). Please see [*Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310) and act accordingly.